# Besides Cyrus, is there any other human explicitly declared as Mosiach in tanach?

Tags: historical-figures

http://www.cgg.org/index.cfm/fuseaction/Library.sr/CT/PW/k/187/Cyrus-Gods-Anointed.htm

God called Cyrus the great His messiah.

Anyone else got that title?

Comment: 1) We've told you to use Jewish translations before. 2) The examples in the answer below are mentioned already in that article.

Comment: @DoubleAA -- sorry. I didn't read the linked article. I had the verse handy so I just quoted it.

Comment: Saul, David, Solomon, Jehu...

Comment: Finding and quoting an actual verse would probably take you most (or all) of the way to the answer.

Comment: Mosiach can also mean king not just messiah, Cyrus was king not the messiah

Comment: If hashem call Cyrus mosiach, who am I to argue?  Did he bring us to golden age? I would ask for another Adam Smith instead.

Answer (score 2):

Saul, in Shmuel 1, 24:7
And he [David] said to his men, "The Lord forbid it for me, that I should do this thing to my lord, to the Lord's anointed, to stretch forth my hand upon him, for he is the Lord's anointed."

ז. וַיֹּאמֶר לַאֲנָשָׁיו חָלִילָה לִּי מֵיהֹוָה אִם אֶעֱשֶׂה אֶת הַדָּבָר הַזֶּה לַאדֹנִי לִמְשִׁיחַ יְהֹוָה לִשְׁלֹחַ יָדִי בּוֹ כִּי מְשִׁיחַ יְהֹוָה הוּא:

Comment: Also David, in Sh'mu'el Alef 28, and David again in T'hilim 2. And again in Divrei Hayamim. . . to name a few.

Comment: the cohen in Vayikra 4, 6

Comment: Also, "the Lord's anointed, was captured in their pits" in [Eikhah 4:20](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16460#v=20). (One would think it's referring to Tzidqiyahu, but Rhashi on the verse says it's Yoshiyahu.)

Comment: So the word mosiach show up a lot of time on tanach. It's not really special isn't it?